# VBA Word: Excel file keeps opening in ReadOnly Mode

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, readonly, readonly-attribute

As mentioned in the title, an Excel file, which I open from a Word macro keeps  opening in ReadyOnly Mode, no matter what I try.

Here is the code which causes the behavior:

```
Dim wbProcess As Workbook
Dim strDatei As String

strDatei = ActiveDocument.Path & "\Parameters.xlsx"   
Set wbProcess = Workbooks.Open(strDatei, IgnoreReadOnlyRecommended:=True, ReadOnly:=False)  

Excel.Application.Visible = True
```

Or could it be some other settings, not in VBA specific?

Comment: Is the file located on a server, where someone else is already accessing?

Comment: You should also show us more of your code - the parts that initiate Excel, for example. And do you have a reference to the Excel libary in the Word VBA project?

Comment: The references are all activated and the file is on an local folder. Excel itself is initiated in on Sub-Level, while this is just a Function. However it works now somehow... If I were to save the "Parameters" file with .save, it gives me an error, but at least I can write in the File now. I don´t even want to save it, so everything is fine now. Even though I didn´t changed anything in the code about this topic. (That's what I think at least) But thank you for your time:)

Comment: Sometimes, restarting the application(s) or Windows can have good effects on "odd" behavior :-) Glad it's working!